# i want to make many different images but this just show up Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to make many different images using listView builder [image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image.asset takes  a string not, in this case you can either have your widgets as

```
list a =[

'assets/myimage.png',
'assets/myimage.png']
```

or change the Image.asset in your listview to
as your `list a =[]` returns a widget of type `Image.asset`

```
return a[index]
```

Comment: thank you so much have a great day!

Comment: do upvote if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You are using redundand `Image.asset`.

Your code at line 25:

`return Image.asset(Image.asset('.../.../sth.png'))`

Change 25 line to :

`return a[index]`

You can read more about this topic here:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: thank you so much have a great day!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).